# kube-bench is not applying on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kube-bench

I am trying to apply the kube-bench on k8s cluster on gcp environment. while creating the cluster it is failing with message:

```
Error: failed to generate container "<container_id>" spec: failed to generate spec: failed to mkdir "/srv/kubernetes": mkdir /srv: read-only file system
```

job.yml:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: kube-bench-master
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      hostPID: true
      nodeSelector:
        node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          operator: Exists
          effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
        - name: kube-bench
          image: aquasec/kube-bench:latest
          command: ["kube-bench", "run", "--targets", "master"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: var-lib-etcd
              mountPath: /var/lib/etcd
              readOnly: true
            - name: var-lib-kubelet
              mountPath: /var/lib/kubelet
              readOnly: true
            - name: var-lib-kube-scheduler
              mountPath: /var/lib/kube-scheduler
              readOnly: true
            - name: var-lib-kube-controller-manager
              mountPath: /var/lib/kube-controller-manager
              readOnly: true
            - name: etc-systemd
              mountPath: /etc/systemd
              readOnly: true
            - name: lib-systemd
              mountPath: /lib/systemd/
              readOnly: true
            - name: srv-kubernetes
              mountPath: /srv/kubernetes/
              readOnly: true
            - name: etc-kubernetes
              mountPath: /etc/kubernetes
              readOnly: true
              # /usr/local/mount-from-host/bin is mounted to access kubectl / kubelet, for auto-detecting the Kubernetes version.
              # You can omit this mount if you specify --version as part of the command.
            - name: usr-bin
              mountPath: /usr/local/mount-from-host/bin
              readOnly: true
            - name: etc-cni-netd
              mountPath: /etc/cni/net.d/
              readOnly: true
            - name: opt-cni-bin
              mountPath: /opt/cni/bin/
              readOnly: true
            - name: etc-passwd
              mountPath: /etc/passwd
              readOnly: true
            - name: etc-group
              mountPath: /etc/group
              readOnly: true
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: var-lib-etcd
          hostPath:
            path: "/var/lib/etcd"
        - name: var-lib-kubelet
          hostPath:
            path: "/var/lib/kubelet"
        - name: var-lib-kube-scheduler
          hostPath:
            path: "/var/lib/kube-scheduler"
        - name: var-lib-kube-controller-manager
          hostPath:
            path: "/var/lib/kube-controller-manager"
        - name: etc-systemd
          hostPath:
            path: "/etc/systemd"
        - name: lib-systemd
          hostPath:
            path: "/lib/systemd"
        - name: srv-kubernetes
          hostPath:
            path: "/srv/kubernetes"
        - name: etc-kubernetes
          hostPath:
            path: "/etc/kubernetes"
        - name: usr-bin
          hostPath:
            path: "/usr/bin"
        - name: etc-cni-netd
          hostPath:
            path: "/etc/cni/net.d/"
        - name: opt-cni-bin
          hostPath:
            path: "/opt/cni/bin/"
        - name: etc-passwd
          hostPath:
            path: "/etc/passwd"
        - name: etc-group
          hostPath:
            path: "/etc/group"
```

[git link](https://github.com/aquasecurity/kube-bench#installation)

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to create folder inside folder with permission *ReadOnly.*

The easiest workaround to make it work is changing your path form:

```yaml
            - name: srv-kubernetes
              mountPath: /srv/kubernetes/
```

to f.e. :

```yaml
            - name: srv-kubernetes
              mountPath: /tmp/kubernetes/
```

The second solution is to change permissions for this folder.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577494/mkdir-mnt-data-read-only-file-system-back-off-restarting-failed-postgres-conta/62581280#62581280) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544370/kubernetes-how-to-set-volumemount-user-group-and-file-permissions) questions with helpful answers, connected to your issue.

Comment: i am using docker instance to scan cluster